# MVC 4 Beta - You must write an attribute 'type'='object' after writing the attribute with local name '__type'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with the WebAPI in the new MVC 4 Beta.  I came across this error when trying to get an entity that has a `virtual ICollection<>` property to populate.  Is there a way to get around this as of right now?  I understand this is in the Beta stage, so this might be fixed down the road.  It was just a curiosity if there is a solution out there for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by removing the virtual keyword and making sure that the objects and collections that did have a virtual keyword were provided in the Include statement within my repository.

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public interface IOrderRepository
{
    IQueryable<Order> Orders { get; }
    void SaveOrder(Order order);
    void DeleteOrder(Order order);
}

public class OrderRepository
{
    StoreDbContext db = new StoreDbContext();

    public IQueryable<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return db.Orders.Include("Products"); }
    }

    public void SaveOrder(Order order)
    {
        db.Entry(order).State = order.ID == 0 ? 
                EntityState.Added : 
                EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void DeleteOrder(Order order)
    {
        db.Orders.Remove(order);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the error is related to serializing the auto-generated proxies AND if you don't really need them then you might just need to disable proxy creation on your context... Here is a similar Q/A...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173524/webapi-with-ef-code-first-generates-error-when-having-parent-child-relation

Comment: Here's another solution which probably is more efficient http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235650/entity-framework-serialize-poco-to-json

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it seems to be a problem with the default WebApi serializer. 
I added Json.Net as a formatter in my Global.asax.cs and it worked fine for me.
I just followed this example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx

This is what I've got in my Global.asax.cs

```
JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters[0] = new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings);
```

I just added the Json.Net package using NuGet and created the JsonNetFormatter class as explained in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I fixed it by using a sort of ViewModel class that only had simple types.  I translated the object returned by the DbContext into my ViewModel class and passed that back to the client.

This wouldn't work in all situations, but it did in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem also. My situation was a little different though.

I had this structure and it would not work for me.

```
[DataContract]
public class MJPEGCamera : Camera
{
}
[DataContract]
public class H264Camera : Camera
{     
}
[DataContract]
public class Camera
{
    [DataMember]
    public string cameraName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string address { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string format { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string archiveDaysUrl { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string archiveHoursUrl { get; private set; }
}
```

So I just created a factory in camera to accomplish what I needed. Hope this will help somebody who finds this answer.